# Replace in Mathematica

Tags: replacement, pattern-matching

I have:
$$X=Z+22*Y$$
$$Y=P$$

Edited:
Is there a way to replace $Y$ in the first expression using Mathematica?
I tried Replace and it's not giving the desired result.

Can I replace both Z and Y at the same time. What I meant is more than one variable at the same time. Eg:
I have $$X=Z+22*Y+33*Q$$
I need to replace  $Y$ with $P$, $Q$ with $M$ and $Z$ with $L$?
Is there a possibility?

Comment: `x == z + 22 y /. y -> p`

Comment: *"I tried Replace ..."* Please show what you have tried. Post code, not LaTeX.

Comment: `X = Z + 22 Y + 33 Q /. {Y -> P, Q -> M, Z -> L}` Please read the document of `ReplaceAll` (`/.`) carefully by pressing **F1**.

Comment: Sorry that I forgot to update. I got the answer!!

Answer (score 7):

`ReplaceAll` as suggested by cvgmt is more convenient.

If you have to use `Replace`, you can get the desired result using the third argument of `Replace` to specify the level:

```
ClearAll[x, z, y, p]
Replace[x == z + 22 y, y -> p, All]
```

> ```
> x == 22 p + z
> ```

Without the third argument, default level specification `{0}` is used. To see the effect of level specification inspect:

```
expr = x == z + 22 y;
Grid[Prepend[{#, Level[expr, #], Replace[expr, y -> p, #]} & /@ 
   Append[List /@ Range[Depth@expr] - 1, All], 
  {"levelspec", "Level[x == z + 22 y, levelspec]", 
   "Replace[x == z + 22 y, y -> p, levelspec]"}], Dividers -> All]
```

[image]

**Update:** Per pudepied's suggestion using `TreeForm` or `ExpressionGraph` may be useful:

```
eg = ExpressionGraph[expr];

ticks = Thread[{Reverse[Union[GraphEmbedding[eg][[All, 2]]]], 
    Style[#, 16] &@Row[{"Level ", #}] & /@ List /@ Range[0, 3]}];

Show[SetProperty[eg, 
  {VertexLabels -> {v_ :> Placed[Style[ "Subexpression" /. (v /. 
        AnnotationValue[eg, AnnotationRules]), 16], After]}}], 
 ImageSize -> Large, Frame -> True, 
 PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.1], 
 FrameTicks -> {{None, ticks}, {None, None}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Great answer. Love the grid format explanation. Also interesting in the light of running ```x == z + 22 y // TreeForm```.

Comment: Could the visualization be further improved using `Depth` to get rid of the "magic numbers"?

Comment: @Natas, good idea. We can use `List /@ Range[Depth[x == z + 22 y]] - 1`. Updated with your suggestion.

Comment: Great answer. I have edited my question. Can you please have a look?